# visincr.vim compatibility with Neovim

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, vimball

In Vim 7.4, I used to effectively deploy the [`visincr.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) plugin for such a task. However, I have recently moved to neovim and this won't work anymore.

The errors produced by `:so %` fills up the whole screen. Every line in the vimball raises the standard error: `Not an editor command.`, followed by insanely long lines of cryptic characters and control sequences such as `<e4><ab>͔<f8><94><99>`.

Can anyone advise on the compatibility of this vimball plugin and neovim ?

Update:

I have unzipped the file and tried again. Now, it gives the following error:

```
E492: Not an editor command : UseVimball
```

Update 2:
This has now been solved. I had to run :packadd vimball before attempting :so %.  The vimball also had to be moved to one of the $VIMRUNTIME directories.  Thanks to all who helped :)

Comment: as far as i know, vimballs should still be usable with neovim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, when I open the visincr.vba.gz file and type :so % , my screen gets filled with errors like the following. line    1:                                                                                                                                        
E492: Not an editor command: ^_<8b>^H^HU<dc><d5>

Comment: Do you have a link to this file? Also, you can [edit] the question to include extra information such as errors (that doesn't work very well in comments due to limited formatting).

Comment: That is useful information you should have mentioned in your question! Try unzipping the file manually before sourcing it. Perhaps the gzip autocommand is not run correctly for your neovim installation.

Comment: As a point of interest, VimBalls were not removed in NeoVim. See [#2231](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2231#issuecomment-85511234): *"We'll just keep vimball unless/until a better alternative arrives"*.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I have updated the question with this info. Meanwhile, I have unzipped the file and tried again. Now, it gives the following error: "E492: Not an editor command : UseVimball"

Comment: looks like vimball plugin is not installed properly. Is the vimballPlugin.vim file located in your $VIMRUNTIME path?

Comment: It's exracted to ~/.config/nvim/autoload/visincr.vba .

I have cd'ed to the folder, and then open the visincr.vba file in neovim. When I run :so % , I get the "E492: Not an editor command : UseVimball" error

Comment: You need to use `:packadd vimball` first, since this plugin is no longer loaded automatically (it's in `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/vimball` on my system).

Comment: That is wrong, you need `~/.config/nvim/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim` and `~/.config/nvim/autoload/vimball.vim` and `~/.config/nvim/doc/pi_vimball.txt` for the documentation.

Comment: Dear Carpetsmoker and Christian Brabandt. Thanks a lot to both of you. That solved the issue !  The plugin is working fine.  do I need to edit the question further or upvote an answer to mark as solved ?